# Spring boot inject mongodb datasource

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, cloud-foundry, spring-data-mongodb

I am trying to deploy a spring boot application connected to a mongodb instance to cloud foundry.

```
cf create-service MongoService default my-mongo
cf push myapp --no-start
cf bind-service myapp my-mongo
cf start myapp
```

The connection details to the mongodb instance are in the `VCAP_SERVICES` environment variable. When deploying my application to cloudfoundry spring boot is trying to access mongodb on localhost:27017 and obviously fails.

I would like to parse the `VCAP_SERVICES` environment variable, construct some mongodb connection details from it and provide this as a spring bean. Which class should I use for these configuration details?

Comment: I have solved the issue by registering a Configuration class that extends `AbstractMongoConfiguration`. In this class the vcap_services environment variable is parsed, and inserted into the Mongo object returned by the override mongo() method.

Comment: Please show more details how you fixed it, I am having the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

With Spring Boot, you don't need to manually parse VCAP_SERVICES. If you are using MongoTemplate or MongoRepository, it will automatically connect to the bound instance.

Make sure that you have **spring-boot-starter-parent** identified as the parent artifact in your pom.xml.

You can add the following to your pom.xml to ensure that the cloud connector code is getting picked up:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cloud-connectors</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Of course, you also need the MongoDB Spring Data dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: I tried exactly this, but the app still tries to connect to localhost:27017.

Comment: When adding this to the POM, do I need to add any other annotations to make this work? I am having the same problem as user152469

Comment: Be sure you have included the mongodb data dependency. groupId:org.springframework.boot
   artifactId:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try setting up the configuration parameters, like a workaround I had to implement with MySQL, check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37486769/selecting-parameters-that-should-be-used-by-spring-boot-when-creating-datasource).

For me it all came down to properly defining following properties:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://${vcap.services.mydb.credentials.host}:${vcap.services.mydb.credentials.port}/${vcap.services.mydb.credentials.name}
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    username: ${vcap.services.mydb.credentials.user}
    password: ${vcap.services.mydb.credentials.password}
```